# Issues with GraphQL Nested Mutation

Tags: graphql, mutation

I am trying to achieve nesting mutation by adding player name in Team (Parent) and struggling trying to fetch list of player name...

Inside GraphiQL tool (localhost:4000/graphiql), this is the Add Mutation variable that I have included...

```
mutation AddPlayerToTeam($name: String!, $teamId: ID!){
  addPlayerToTeam(player: $name, teamId: $teamId){
    id
    players{
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The query variables, adding teamID and name...

```
{
  "teamId": "5aff545371fc930a4c43b2b9",
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

The result shown...

```
{
  "data": {
    "addPlayerToTeam": {
      "id": "5b072774e385740c38483111",
      "players": []
    }
  }
}
```

But I was expecting for player name to show up like this....

```
{
  "data": {
    "addPlayerToTeam": {
      "id": "5b072774e385740c38483111",
      "players": [
         { 
           "name": "John Doe"
         }
       ]
     }
  }
}
```

The mutation code...

```
AddPlayerToTeam: {
    type: TeamType,
    args: {
            name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
            teamId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
        },
        resolve(parent, { name, teamId }) {
            let addPlayer = new Player({ name, teamId });
            return addPlayer.save();
        }
    },
```

I've struggled to find reason why I am getting `"players": []` instead of `"players": [ {"name": "John Doe" } ]`. 
Need I include `.then(...)` after `.save()` to get result? Any examples? Your help is appreciated.

BTW, I using mongoDB/mongoose method. Saving them in local mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for this... Thank #andrewingram from graphql.slack for helping. Just include `.then(...)` to return result.

```
AddPlayerToTeam: {
    type: TeamType,
    args: {
        name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        teamId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
    },
    async resolve(parent, { name, teamId }) {
        let addPlayer = new Player({ name, teamId });
        await addPlayer.save();
        return Team.findById(teamId);
    }
},
```

or in promise version

```
resolve(parent, { name, teamId }) {
        let addPlayer = new Player({ name, teamId });
        return addPlayer.save().then(() => Team.findById(teamId));
    }
```

Hope that help.